# GDALOpenEx() doesn't works anymore with iOS 12

Tags: gdal, ios

I'm using GDAL in a iOS application. Everything was fine since the iOS 12 SDK update. Now, when I try to open a database (.sqlite file here) with this line

```
GDALOpenEx(dataSourceConnectionString.c_str(), openFlags, NULL, NULL, NULL));
```

dataSourceConnectionString is equivalent to

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E2E5852A-F597-40F8-86FC-7BAFA298CCD2/Documents/data/database.sqlite
```

The path is correct and the file exists. The error number raised by GDALOpenEx is *4*, which means the file is not recognized as a supported file format.

It works perfectly well if the app is running on iPad under iOS 11, but it doesn't anymore if it's iOS 12.

Has anyone experienced similar issues with GDAL/sqlite3 and iOS 12 update ?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue with both iOS 13 and 14, I'm using GDAL 2.4.2. We are currently looking for fixes in newer versions but no lead for now.